# Azure ARM Template to Create Linux VM and Add Line to /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, powershell, azure, azure-rm-template

We have an ARM template that correctly creates a Linux VM via a powershell command:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateFile .\template.json -TemplateParameterFile .\parameters.json -ResourceGroupName my-rg -virtualMachineName my-test-vm
```

We would like to leverage the CustomScriptForLinux extension to add a line /etc/hosts

Here is the relevant part of the template.json:

```
{
      "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'/edithosts')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "dependsOn": [
          "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
            "publisher": "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions",
             "type": "CustomScriptForLinux",
             "typeHandlerVersion": "1.5",
             "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
             "settings": {
               "commandToExecute": "sudo echo '10.X.X.X  sample.acme.com' >> /etc/hosts"
           }
    }
  }
],
```

The deployment succeeds without error, but the /etc/hosts file does not have the new line.

The output from /var/log/azure/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux/1.5.2.2/extension.log includes:

```
Command to execute:sudo echo '10.X.X.X  sample.acme.com' >> /etc/hosts
2018/03/20 15:22:29 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.2] Command is finished.
2018/03/20 15:22:29 ---stdout---
2018/03/20 15:22:29 10.X.X.X  sample.acme.com >> /etc/hosts
2018/03/20 15:22:29
2018/03/20 15:22:29 ---errout---
2018/03/20 15:22:29
2018/03/20 15:22:29
```

Removing 'sudo' from the command makes no difference.

Comment: `/bin/bash -c echo bla-bla-bla`?

Comment: Yes, it turns out to not directly be an Azure issue, but Azure silently runs the 'commandToExecute' within sudo which treats the redirect as applying to sudo rather than echo. 

This works:
"commandToExecute": "bash -c \"echo '10.X.X.X sample.acme.com' >> /etc/hosts"

Comment: @4c74356b41 If you put your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to use `bash -c "echo '10.X.X.X sample.acme.com' >> etc/hosts"` to make linux parse the input from script extension properly